# linux orphan socket listener issue

Tags: java, linux, sockets, file-descriptor, orphan

I have come up with an unusual state of a socket and wanted to know if anyone can explain it.

- The OS in question is: Linux SLES11SP2-2 Revision 0 ia32e
- The java version used is: 1.7.0.45-64

I have a running java process which listens on port N using the TCP protocol.
The java process successfully binded to that port at startup and is waiting on an accept() method on it.
At some unknown point the java process has lost the file descriptor that was listening to that port but it still wait on the accept() method an no close() method was called on it.

- Looking at the output (as root) of ‘lsof’, no process is holding that port.

  `/root ! #  lsof | grep N`
- Looking at the output (as root) of ‘fuser’, no process is holding that port.

  `/root ! #  fuser –n tcp N`
- Looking at the output of the ‘ss’  (as root), no process is holding that port.

  `/root ! #  ss -ltp | grep N
  129    128                          *:31526                         *:*`
- Looking at ‘netstat’ (as root) the socket is Listening but without any process related to it (but it does have an inode number)

  `root ! #  netstat -putane | grep N
  tcp      129      0 0.0.0.0:N        0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      0          1488959042 -
  tcp      661      0 X0.X1.X2.X3:N    Y0.Y1.Y2.Y3:N1     CLOSE_WAIT  0          0          -
  tcp     1982      0 X0.X1.X2.X3:N    Y0.Y1.Y2.Y3:N2     CLOSE_WAIT  0          0          -
  …`
- Searching through the /proc/*/fd/* for a reference to that inode came up empty.

  `/root ! #  find /proc/*/fd/* -exec stat {} \; | grep 1488959042`
- Looking for that inode in the /proc/net/etc gave the following result:

  `/root ! #  cat /proc/net/tcp | grep 1488959042
  5: 00000000:7B26 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000081 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 1488959042 1 ffff88179d96af40 300 0 0 2 -1`
- Using telnet to connect to that port is working and data can be sent to it.

  `/root ! #  telnet localhost N`
- Trying to acquire the port from a new process fails with error indicating the address is in use.
- There are no orphans listed in the kernal, not does it reach the limit of orphans.

  `/root ! #  cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_orphans
  262144`

  `/root ! #  cat /proc/net/sockstat
  sockets: used 179
  TCP: inuse 111 orphan 0 tw 33 alloc 164 mem 346
  UDP: inuse 17 mem 11
  UDPLITE: inuse 0
  RAW: inuse 0
  FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0`
- The tcp memory is not breached as well.

  `/root ! #  cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mem
  2326728 3102307 4653456`

So here are my questions:

1. How can that situation occur where an active socket is being detached from a running process?
2. How can I close the orphan socket so I can bind to it again?

Looking online came up empty and the only information regarding orphan sockets refer to kernel based ports (such as NFS service ports) and sockets stuck in TIME_WAIT state which should be cleared by the kernel after a certain timeout.

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this a real problem? Is it preventing you from doing anything? such as restarting the server on the same port?

Comment: Hi, This is indeed a real problem. I put on a monitor to reatart the java process when it happens,  but I'd rather it won't happen at all...